# How does one know which will be kept current: Snap, Flatpak, or Debian

Tags: package-management, snap, debian, flatpak

For a month or more Libre Office debian package has been at version 5.4.4.  However, the snap package version is still only at 5.4.3.  It seems in this case, for some unknown reason, the snap package is not being kept current.  This makes me think of a more general problem/question:

In the future, when a system will have a mix of debian, snap, and even flatpak packages available for the various applications, how would a person know for each application which packaging type the provider will keep current?

Comment: I don't understand what it was about my original wording of the question that made it seem "opinion-based", and thus put it on hold.  I read the rules, I disagree that it was opinion-based.  However, I don't mind rewording it - the problem is, I don't know the mysterious reasons it was considered to be opinion-based, so I don't know how best to reword it.  (I tried, I hope it is ok now.)  It is not an opinion that the debian and snap packages are at different versions - I want to know how a person can know  which package will be the current version of an application.

Comment: The answer will differ based on the package. In general, the APT packages only come out with security fixes until you upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu. The difference between Snap and Flatpak depend on the efforts of the maintainer for that specific package, and is more a question of their reputation in updating it promptly than something we can answer here ahead of time for each package.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex maybe it's possible for someone to write an answer explaining the variables involved, why a general answer isn't possible, and how you might make a decision for a particular package? Your comment goes quite a long way towards doing that...

Answer (score 4):

Both snap and flatpak applications have some similarities. And as of your doubt regarding security features,

> Snap and Flatpak packages come with security benefits. They are sandboxed. Apps can only see themselves and parts of the computer they have permission to see. This isolation prevents software from easily damaging other parts of the system.

But this comes with some problems as well.

> The situation isn’t foolproof. The X11 window system used by most Linux distros limits the security of both formats. This should change once the Wayland and Mir display servers are ready for primetime.

All these useful information comes from [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/snaps-vs-flatpaks-whats-difference/), have a look into it for further info.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I am still left wondering - How will a person know for an application which will be the current version:  debian, snap, or flatpak?  Now that we are "forced" into an era in which an application could have all these types of packages, I would like to know how I can know which will be the most current.  As you can see from my question, with LibreOffice the snap package is not kept current.

Comment: That depends on the team that builds the specific package isn't it? See, snap is developed by canonical and flatpak's by gnome. So basically all the products that comes from canonical will be freshly available from if it is a snap app. Same with the case of flatpak and gnome. But there are independent programmers out there who still release their software in deb packages. And if you are using it the deb packages will have the most updated version. It is just a matter of time though, which will be released ahead of which one

Comment: In case of Libreoffice, the developers are using debian package method rather than snap and flatpak. so you are getting it as a much new software. but both snap and flatpak is gaining popularity as fast as possible. Free softwares (not opensource) have been built in snap apps mostly. So if you are using it you must go with snap apps rather than deb.